# OleDbAdapter performance issue

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, ado

Currently we are using in our company OleDb in an older application.

I have started to profilng the application and dotTrace said me that this code is one of the bottlenecks. In total it takes about 18s for execution (avg 6ms).

```
m_DataSet = new DataSet("CommandExecutionResult");
m_DataAdapter.SelectCommand = m_OleDbCommand;
m_DataAdapter.Fill(m_DataSet, "QueryResult");    // <-- bottleneck
ReturnValue = m_DataSet.Tables[0].Copy();
m_InsertedRecordId = -1;
m_EffectedRecords = m_DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

I know, maybe there some ways to reduce the number of queries. BUT is there a way to get a DataTable from an access database without using the DataAdapter?

Comment: And how long does it take to get query's results in ms access ?

Comment: The number of queries here appears to be "1". I suspect that the fundamental issue here is the quantity of data: how many rows/columns are you fetching here? Or if it isn't data *volume*, then it would most likely be the query itself, and the performance of that - which is up to the provider and database (access in this case, it looks like). While I'm no lover of `DataTable` / `DataAdapter`, I suspect it is premature to blame *them* for this...

Comment: It is not only one query.

Comment: There are several queries. I guess somethink about 10k. I think I have reduce the number of queries :-(

Comment: I think it is normal for this line to take longer than the rest of the code if you have a lot of data that you are loading into your dataset. Although it is one query, but it could be scanning and retrieving a lot of rows...